# Given a matrix $A$ of rank $n$, show that $\det(\operatorname{adj}(A))=\det(A)^{n-1}$ and $\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A))=(\det A)^{n-2}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$\newcommand{\adj}{\operatorname{adj}}\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$If $\adj(A)$ denotes the classical adjoint and we are given that, for an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{R}$,

$$\rank(\adj(A)) = \begin{cases} n& \rank(A)=n\\1& \rank(A)=n-1\\0& \rank(A)<n-1\end{cases}$$

show that for $n \geq 2$

1. $\det(\adj(A)) = \det(A)^{n-1};$
2. $\adj(\adj(A)) = \det(A)^{n-2}A.$

---

The first is easy, actually. If $\rank(A) = n$, $\adj(A)A = \det(A)I$; taking determinants of both sides easily yields the result; if $\rank(A) < n$, $\det(A) = 0 = \det(\adj(A))$.

Comment: See Theorem 5.12 in my *The trace Cayley-Hamilton theorem* ( http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/trach.pdf ). The proof there works over an arbitrary ring (and thus, in particular, does not rely on the rank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), if $rank(A) = n$, $adj(A)A = det(A)I$; taking determinants of both sides easily yields the result; if $rank(A) < n$, $det(A) = 0 = det(adj(A))$.

For (2), we use (1). If $rank A = n$, then

$$\begin{align}
adj(adj(A))adj(A) &= det(adj(A))I\\
 &= det(adj(A)) (1/det(A))adj(A)A\\
 &= det(adj(A))^{n-2} adj(A)A
adj(adj(A)) = det(adj(A))^{n-2}A,
\end{align}
$$

and, if $rank(A) < 0$, both sides are again zero.

Comment: Some inaccuracies and minor bugs here. You probably don't want $rank(A) < 0$. Moreover, if $n = 2$, then $rank(A) < n$ does not imply $\operatorname{adj} A = 0$.