# Show that $adj(adj(A)) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n > 2$ and let $A$ be a real and singular (i.e., non-invertible)  $n\times n$ matrix. Is it true that $adj(adj(A)) = 0$ ?

Comment: A stronger result: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649187/prove-that-if-a-is-regular-then-operatornameadj-operatornameadja) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091072/given-a-matrix-a-of-rank-n-show-that-det-operatornameadja-deta?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Hint : What is the adjugate matrix is the rank of A is strictly less than $n-1$? And what is the rank of $\text{adj}(A)$ when $\text{rk}(A)=n-1$?